# Send state to the require source of the image tag in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to transform the item.Hinh to show an image but react doesn't seem to understand. I have also tried many ways before. Some of the remaining syntax errors do not show errors but no images

```
export default class List1 extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state ={
  data:[],
  isLoading: true
};
}
render(){
  const { data, isLoading } = this.state;
  return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1,flexDirection: 'row' }}>
         {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
           <FlatList
             data={data}
             keyExtractor={({ Id }, index) => Id}
             renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{flex:1,height: 100,marginVertical:20}}>

               <Image source={require(item.Hinh)}  />     <-this error here
               <Text>{item.Hinh}</Text>
               <Text>{item.Ten}</Text>
               <Text>{item.Gia}</Text>
         </View>

             )}
           />
         )}
       </View>
     );
  }
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/webbanhang/Sever.php')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
          console.log(json);
          this.setState({ data: json });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });

  }
}
```

At the Server, I get data from mysql into json form and give react use the data and this is my JSON:
*[{"Id":"1000","Ten":"Nh\u00e2n S\u1ea9m","Gia":"3000000","Hinh":" './camthao3.jpg' "},{"Id":"1001","Ten":"H\u1eadu Ph\u00e1c","Gia":"230000","Hinh":" './camthao3.jpg' "},{"Id":"1012","Ten":"vicky","Gia":"231213131","Hinh":" './camthao3.jpg' "},{"Id":"1013","Ten":"Qu\u1ebf","Gia":"30000","Hinh":" './camthao3.jpg' "}]*

```
<?php
class Sanpham{
public $Id;
public $Ten;
public $Gia;
 function Sanpham($i, $t, $g, $h)
{
$this->Id = $i;
$this->Ten =  $t;
$this->Gia=  $g;
$this->Hinh =  $h;
}

}
$item = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345678", "quanlysieuthi");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM webthaoduoc.sanpham";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $a =  './iama3.jpg';
      $item[] = new Sanpham($row['id'],$row['tensp'],$row['giaban'],$a);
   }
}
else {
    echo "No record";
}
echo  json_encode($item);
?>
```